# Why rasa init giving error:not recognised

Tags: rasa, rasa-core, rasa-x

(installingrasa) C:\Users\DEVENDER\Rasa_Chatbot\Rasa_project>rasa init
'rasa' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Hi there! It seems that the `rasa` command is not in your path, and your shell cannot find it. Could you add more details on how you installed rasa? I also suggest to ask this kind of question in our our forum (https://forum.rasa.com/), where the community will also be able to help you :)

Comment: 1.(base) C:\Users\DEVENDER>pip3 --version
pip 20.3.3 from c:\users\devender\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)

2.
(base) C:\Users\DEVENDER>python --version
Python 3.7.0

3.
(base) C:\Users\DEVENDER>python -m venv ./venv

4.

(base) C:\Users\DEVENDER>.\venv\Scripts\activate

(venv) (base) C:\Users\DEVENDER>

5.
pip3 install rasa

6.
rasa init
AttributeError: module 'sip' has no attribute 'setapi'

Comment: how to set the path

Comment: I'm not well versed in Windows, but you could follow this tutorial: https://codingbee.net/powershell/powershell-make-a-permanent-change-to-the-path-environment-variable